# which port is proper to start apache except port:80?

Tags: apache, xampp

I've just installed XAMPP. Apache doesn't start because of the blocked ports.I deactivated apps and services which use port 80 but it didn't work. at last, I set it to listen on port :8080 ( through httpd.conf) but it still repeated that error:

> Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>       This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>       improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>       Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>       the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>       If you need more help, copy and post this
>       entire log window on the forums

now I guess i may set it to another port but dont know which?

Comment: As stated by the error message itself, the port is only one of the possibile problems that shutdown Apache. Are you starting xampp as administrator?

Comment: You can set any port that is not in use. What OS are you using? Also check the log files, you may find the problem is a bad configuration.

Comment: yeah i start xampp as an administrator. I'm on windows 8 . The log files dont return any error